# What Syntax is this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The left side is a variable name but then on the right side there are two instances separated by comma. I have never seen that before?

```
var MarkerAnnotation = mapkit.MarkerAnnotation,
    clickAnnotation;
```

Comment: just the standard of declaring variables, with the first getting an initial value.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as

```
var MarkerAnnotation = mapkit.MarkerAnnotation;
var clickAnnotation;
```

To expand a little, most of the time you'll see it as

```
var foo, bar, baz;

// or

var foo,
    bar,
    baz;
```

...but the introduction of the object property assignment does make it look a bit unclear, especially with the indentation.

Comment: Thanks! I would never it. Looks so weird.